# char16_t and char32_t endianness

Tags: c, endianness, c11, char16-t, char32-t

In C11, support for portable wide char types `char16_t` and `char32_t` are [added](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1286.pdf) for UTF-16 and UTF-32 respectively.

However, in the technical report, there is no mention of endianness for these two types.

For example, the following snippet in `gcc-4.8.4` on my x86_64 computer when compiled with `-std=c11`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uchar.h>

char16_t utf16_str[] = u"十六";  // U+5341 U+516D
unsigned char *chars = (unsigned char *) utf16_str;
printf("Bytes: %X %X %X %X\n", chars[0], chars[1], chars[2], chars[3]);
```

will produce

```
Bytes: 41 53 6D 51
```

Which means that it's little-endian.

But is this behaviour platform/implementation dependent: does it always adhere to the platform's endianness or may some implementation choose to always implement `char16_t` and `char32_t` in [big-endian](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2781#section-4.3)?

Comment: Suggest adding "why" endianness is important for the code.  How does code plan to use the endianness? To make some conversion easier using type spoofing?  IMO, endianness should play a minuscule role in robust portable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char16_t` and `char32_t` do not guarantee Unicode encoding. (That is a C++ feature.) The macros `__STDC_UTF_16__` and `__STDC_UTF_32__`, respectively, indicate that Unicode code points actually determine the fixed-size character values. See C11 §6.10.8.2 for these macros.

(By the way, `__STDC_ISO_10646__` indicates the same thing for `wchar_t`, and it also reveals which Unicode edition is implemented via `wchar_t`. Of course, in practice, the compiler simply copies code points from the source file to strings in the object file, so it doesn't need to know much about particular characters.)

Given that Unicode encoding is in effect, code point values stored in `char16_t` or `char32_t` must have the same object representation as `uint_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`, because they are defined to be `typedef` aliases to those types, respectively (C11 §7.28). This is again somewhat in contrast to C++, which makes those types distinct but explicitly requires compatible object representation.

The upshot is that yes, there is nothing special about `char16_t` and `char32_t`. They are ordinary integers in the platform's endianness.

However, your test program has nothing to do with endianness. It simply uses the values of the wide characters without inspecting how they map to bytes in memory.

Answer (score 3):

> However, in the technical report, there is no mention of endianness for these two types.

Indeed. The C standard doesn't specify much regarding the representation of multibyte characters in source files.

> ```
> char16_t utf16_str[] = u"十六"; // U+5341 U+516D
> printf("U+%X U+%X\n", utf_16_str[0], utf_16_str[1]);
> ```
>
> will produce
>       U+5341 U+516D
>   Which means that it's little-endian.
>
> But is this behaviour platform/implementation dependent: does it always adhere to the platform's endianness or may some implementation choose to always implement `char16_t` and `char32_t` in big-endian?

**Yes**, The behaviour is *implementation dependent*, as you call it. See C11§5.1.1.2:

> Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped, in an implementation-defined manner, to the source character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary.

That is, whether the multibyte characters in your source code are considered big endian or little endian is implementation-defined. I would advise using something like `u"\u5341\u516d"`, if portability is an issue.

Comment: I updated the snippet to print out `unsigned char`s directly to make my intentions clear. If `char32_t` was encoded with big-endian, printf("U+%X\n", utf16_str[0]) would have resulted in `U+4153` because `unsigned int` is little-endian on x86_64.

Comment: That makes your intentions no more clear. An implementation may use a little endian source character set and a big endian execution character set. Consider cross-compiling, for example.

Comment: Nonetheless, I've updated my answer because I realised what you were actually asking about... See the update.

Comment: But why would the source character set matter here? No matter if I save the snippet in UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE, the first character in `utf16_str` would always have the code point of 0x5341 in UTF-16.

Comment: Translation phase 1 (which I quoted) says multibyte characters are mapped in an implementation-defined manner. Why? It is because it is.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-16 and UTF-32 does not have an endianness defined. They are usually encoded in the hosts native byte ordering. This is why there are Byte Order Markers (BOM) which can be inserted at the beginning of the string to indicate the endianness for an UTF-16 or UTF-32 string.

Comment: What is the good practice when this data is from a file with a BOM, to switch the bytes or to touch nothing but interpret while reading?